# Why does the erase command end my while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop

So I have a piece of code which works pretty well. The goal was to filter through my whatsapp - chat history. First thing I wanted was to sort out such that only my messages which start with 'Ben: ...' are sorted out and the rest discarded.

I succeeded with this but only because of a weird feature I can't understand. Because of some older attempts **I have an erase command in my code, that for now has no real purpose. Yet without it my while loop, keeps looping infinitely.**

Why does the erase command help me finish the loop ?

I tried removing it, and played around with other ideas. Nothing worked.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    string text;
    string deli = "Ben:";

    string token;
    size_t pos = 0;

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("WAEZ.txt");

    while( getline(myfile, text)){
        while((pos = text.find(deli)) != std::string::npos){
            token = text.substr(pos,std::string::npos);
            cout << token << endl;
            text.erase(0, pos + deli.length());
        }
    }    
}
```

I'd like to have this code work without the erase command which I am not using.

Comment: Ask yourself: what is the return value of `text.find(deli)` on the first iteration of the while loop? On the second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text.find(deli))` is finding something in your string, and if it is found, then `text.find(deli)) != std::string::npos` is true. If you call it again with the same `text` and the same `deli`, then the result will be the same.

In your loop, `text.erase(0, pos + deli.length());` changes the string `text`. Without this part, nothing in your loop changes the `text` or the `deli`. That's why it results in an infinite loop: if `text.find(deli)) != std::string::npos` is `true` the first time, it is true forever and nothing will stop it as there also isn't any `break` or any other kind of logic in your code that can get out of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

To mimic your code without erase, you might use the extra parameter of `find` to specify start position of the search:

```
while (getline(myfile, text)) {
    std::size_t origin = 0;
    while((pos = text.find(deli, origin)) != std::string::npos){
        token = text.substr(pos, std::string::npos);
        cout << token << endl;
        origin += deli.length();
    }
}
```

But as you describe your problem, C++20 [`starts_with`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/starts_with) seems fulfill your needs:

```
while (getline(myfile, text)) {
    if (text.starts_with(deli)){
        std::cout << text << std::endl;
    }
}
```